# How to fail a test if element is not present using Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I need to fail test if element is not present using protractor. Here, I have implemented code. When expect condition out of if condition I expected it will fail. Unfortunately, test case is passing. Can anyone suggest if anything that i missed.

```
crossAttribute.isPresent().then(function (deleteAttribute) {
                if(deleteAttribute){
                    crossAttribute.click();
                }else{
                    console.log('Cross is not present to delete attribute') 
                }
                expect(crossAttribute).toBeTruthy;
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will work easily

```
let attributeIsPresent = await crossAttribute.isPresent()
if (attributeIsPresent) {
  await crossAttribute.click();
} else {
  expect(false).toBe(true)
}
```

your code didn't work because you used wrong variable `crossAttribute` instead of `deleteAttribute`

Comment: Sergey, as per above example, I have used the same and it's throwing an error  ```-  Error: Cross is not present to delete attribute``` . But it's not continuing execution and it's aborting. Can you suggest to continue the execution.

Comment: is not it what you wanted?

Comment: or you want to continue with the test case, but just mark it as failed?

Comment: Sergey, yes, want to continue with the test case, but just mark it as failed

Comment: by adding ```expect(false).toBe(true)``` , throwing error and continuing execution.